# If a msg is deleted send another msg Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to do something: If someone say hey, the bot will send "Yes" but if the original msg is deleted ("hey"), I want that the bot send "ahahahahah"

Here's my code :

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if(msg.content.includes("hey")) {
    msg.channel.send("Yes").then(Mess => {
      if(Mess.messageDelete) {
        msg.channel.send('ahahahahah')
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

just use `msg.deleted`:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if(msg.content.includes("hey")) {
    msg.channel.send("Yes").then(Mess => {
      if(msg.deleted) {
        msg.channel.send('ahahahahah')
      }
    })
  }
})
```